# After upgrading Gradle to 3.6.0 native library not found

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

In our project we have module with Jni files located in `modulename/src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a/libname.so`.

After upgrading to Gradle 3.6.0 App can't find this native library file anymore

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0'
    }
```

With Error:

`Error!!! File:/data/app/app.name.com.demo-ABQD5cOg7zEgRy9PxVBtuA==/lib/arm64/libfile.so not found !!!`